# Map pandas dataframe columns to an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this:
[image: Dataframe]

```py
{'choice_0': {0: 52, 1: 26, 2: 100, 3: 2, 4: 53},
 'choice_1': {0: 38, 1: 4, 2: 54, 3: 95, 4: 1},
 'choice_2': {0: 12, 1: 82, 2: 25, 3: 1, 4: 47},
 'choice_3': {0: 82, 1: 5, 2: 12, 3: 96, 4: 93},
 'choice_4': {0: 33, 1: 11, 2: 27, 3: 32, 4: 26},
 'choice_5': {0: 75, 1: 47, 2: 82, 3: 6, 4: 3},
 'choice_6': {0: 64, 1: 38, 2: 10, 3: 40, 4: 46},
 'choice_7': {0: 76, 1: 6, 2: 89, 3: 31, 4: 16},
 'choice_8': {0: 10, 1: 66, 2: 80, 3: 9, 4: 42},
 'choice_9': {0: 28, 1: 61, 2: 33, 3: 59, 4: 39},
 'n_people': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 4}}
```

And an array like:

```py
input_arr = (
    np.array([[   0,   52],
              [   1,   82],
              [   2,  27],
              [   3,   2],
              [   4,   53]]))
```

The first element will be for family_id=0 and column "choice_0" = 52

The second element will be for family_id=1 and column "choice_2" = 82

The third element will be for family_id=2 and column "choice_4" = 27

And I will like to get:

```py
    array([[   0,   0],
    [   1,   2],
    [   2,  3],
    [   3,   0],
    [   4,   0])
```

The logic will be:

- For family_id =0 The initial array has a a 52. And I will like to receive a 0 because it belongs to the "choice_0" column.
- For family_id = 1 The initial array has a 82. And I will like to receive a 2 because it belongs to the "choice_2"column.

Note: Number within a row(family_id) can´t be repeated.

I don´t know even what is the title, feel free to change it.

Comment: what rule/logic should it follow? it's not exactly clear

Comment: @NicolasGervais I tried to explain it a bit better now. Thanks :)

Comment: What if there are duplicate values, for example, famility_id = 0, initial array has a 1, which column should be selected? Also, for the 3rd row in your array with an initial value of 27, why the mapped value is 3? choice_3 doesn't seem to contain 27.

Comment: Also, please give an example data frame with real values, not a screenshot as it's hard to build the test dataset using an image.

Comment: @Allen there can not be duplicated values in the same row. For a certain family choice_Y==choice_X this wont happen. I fixed the error fo the 3rd row

Comment: For the 3rd row, 27 falls under choice_4, should the value be [2,4] instead of [2,3]?

Comment: @Allen I think it is fixed. How do I add a dataframe to SO question so you can easyly copy?

Comment: @CarlosMougan Check out some of the Pandas IO methods. `.to_csv()` is solid, although `.to_dict()` is nice since it can allow you to share small DataFrames directly in the code.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more this feels awkward, or contrived. Do you think there might be a better data structure for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'family_id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'choice_0': {0: 52, 1: 26, 2: 100, 3: 2, 4: 53},
 'choice_1': {0: 38, 1: 4, 2: 54, 3: 95, 4: 1},
 'choice_2': {0: 12, 1: 82, 2: 25, 3: 1, 4: 47},
 'choice_3': {0: 82, 1: 5, 2: 12, 3: 96, 4: 93},
 'choice_4': {0: 33, 1: 11, 2: 27, 3: 32, 4: 26},
 'choice_5': {0: 75, 1: 47, 2: 82, 3: 6, 4: 3}})


input_arr = (
    np.array([[   0,   52],
              [   1,   82],
              [   2,  27]])
)
```

You can get you desired output using a list comprehension.

```
output_arrary=np.array([[e[0], df.iloc[i].tolist().index(e[1])-1] for i, e in enumerate(input_arr)])

print(output_arrary)

[[0 0]
 [1 2]
 [2 4]]
```

Comment: Okey!! Perfect :) Thanks. Also for helping me to improve my question making!!